# I can't connect Chart.JS to the project

Tags: javascript, web, chart.js

Good day! I have a problem. I need to connect a library to the project Chart.js. I used GitHub repository to connect, however there is no output on the resulting page.

Since I need to connect the library to the project first, I created a test directory for connecting it.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
          labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "# of Votes",
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
                "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
              ],
              borderColor: [
                "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
                "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
                "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
                "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
              ],
              borderWidth: 1,
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      });
    </script>

    <script src="js/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? the src might just not be pointing to the right path

Comment: C:.
│   index.html
│   line-boundaries.html
│
├───css
│       Chart.min.css
│       style.css
│       _reset.css
│
└───js
        analyser.js
        Chart.js
        Chart.min.js
        script.js
        utils.js

Comment: make the ```<script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>```  paths relative something like ```src="./pathToJsFolder/Chart.js"```